# Run JS function on Node server after OnClick event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am using **node.js** on **Windows**, with **express** module to generate a static page that has a Submit form which I want to run an `update()` function on the Server (i.e. not expose my js file publicly) when someone clicks "Submit" button.

**PROBLEM:**

It seems my `update()` function fails to be recognized from the HTML. The following error is generated:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):23)

I suspect this is the result of my node project not being set up correctly.

---

**Server file (server.js):**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

//loading all files in public folder
//see instructions in https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(8080);

console.log("Running at Port 8080");
```

**HTML file (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div id="div1">
  <p id="p1">This is a static paragraph.</p>
</div>

<p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="start.js"></script>
</p>

Input:
<br>
<input type="text" name="human_input" value="">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="update()">

</body>
</html>
```

**JS file (compute.js)**

```
function update() {
    console.log("this is running!")
}
```

*^^ note, this is a sample script I am trying to get working.*

**My folder structure**

```
/
- node_modules
-- *
- public
-- start.js
- index.html
- compute.js
- package-lock.json
- server.js
- start.js
```

**Notes:**

- calling `update()` from `onclick` worked previously when I was not using node.

Comment: Node runs on the server side. What you are looking to do is client side execution.

Comment: Maybe you should require the `compute.js` file in your `index.html`? It seems you only require `start.js`? However if you wan't the node server side to communicate you are going to need a transport such as http, web sockets or something similar.

Comment: @PavanAndhukuri, that makes sense. I am happy to refactor my code for server side execution. What would be the first step? Or is there a link to documentation you could provide?

Comment: @nijm you were correct, that got the code working on the client side. I have edited this post for some help on moving the code from client to server side. But happy to go through documentation if you have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss `script` tag in html file pointing on `compute.js` file, that is why your `update` doesn't work.

Just duplicate your `script` you already have in html file and change `src` attribute to `compute.js` value